# imagen de celda se redimensiona al cargar TableView

Tags: swift, swift2

Tengo el siguiente detalle.

Tengo una serie de TableViews, en cuyas celdas estoy cargando imagenes de fondo, tal que asi:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! MenuSecundarioTVCell
    let seccion = items[indexPath.row]


        cell.titulo?.text = (seccion.value["nombre"] as! String)
        //PONIENDO IMAGEN DE FONDO A CELDA
        let imageBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.width , cell.frame.height+1))
        if let imageRemote = seccion.value["imageBackground"]{
            imageRemoteURL = NSURL(string: imageRemote as! String)
            imageBackground.sd_setImageWithURL(imageRemoteURL!)
            cell.backgroundView = UIView()
            cell.backgroundView!.addSubview(imageBackground)
        }
        //TERMINANDO DE PONER IMAGEN DE FONDO A CELDA

    return cell
}
```

Estoy usando [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage). El problema es que cuando las imagenes se cargan en las celdas se ven del siguiente modo:

[image: imagen al cargar vista]

Despues de realizar otra accion como  deslizar las celdas hacia abajo o seleccionar la celda para ir a la siguiente vista, al regresar la imagen se reacomoda quedando de la manera correcta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

las imagenes son de prueba y esta claro que la resolucion de las imagenes no coincide con el alto de las celdas (120)

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 120
    }
```

Sera el origen del problema que la resolución de las imagenes deben coincidir con el tamaño de las celdas?. He visto este problema en algunas apps publicadas en el appstore pero el reacomodo es tan rapido que es casi imperceptible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Añade el `contentMode` el `UIImageView` justo al crearlo para que se vea correctamente desde el principio. Por ejemplo:

```
let imageBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.width , cell.frame.height+1))
imageBackground.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit
```

Comment: Gracias @mhergon ha funcionado, sin embargo la imagen se sigue mostrando igual. Supongo y corrigeme por favor que es por el hecho de que estoy cargando una imagen de dimensiones muy distintas al tamaño de la celda.

Comment: Sí, correcto. En función del parámetro que le pases al contentMode dibujara la imagen de una manera o de otra. Si le pasas .ScaleAspectFill la imagen no se deformará y llenará todo el UIImageView pero no se verá entera. Si ves que se sale, utiliza el parámetro clipToBounds = true para asegurarte que no se muestra imagen más allá de los límites del UIImageView